# "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>" when plotting pandas series data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, typeerror, series

I'm getting an error when trying to plot a bar graph using matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
source_data= pd.read_csv("ehresp_2015.csv")
```

then I extract the two columns from the data set that I need

```
results_1 = source_data[["EUGROSHP","EUGENHTH"]]
```

get rid of the negative values

```
results_1_new = results_1[results_1>0]
```

plot the data

```
x=results_1_new['EUGROSHP']
y=results_1_new['EUGENHTH']
plt.bar([x],[y])
plt.show()
```

I'm getting an error TypeError: cannot convert the series to

Comment: may I remind you of one of the rules here: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]."* In this case, you would create some hardcoded dataset which reproduces the error and include the full errortraceback, not just its last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Series to plot encapsulated in a list, `plt.bar([x],[y]`. This way you would ask matplotlib to plot exactly one bar at position `x` and height `y`. Since `x`, `y` are no numerical values, but Series themselves, this is of course not possible and results in the error `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>`

The solution is quite simple, don't put the Series into lists, but leave them as Series:

```
plt.bar(x,y)
```

---

---

Just to show you how a minimal verifiable example which you may use when asking a question could look like, here a complete code:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
data = pd.DataFrame({"a":np.arange(10)-2,"b":np.random.randn(10)})

results_1 = data[["a","b"]]
results_1_new = results_1[results_1>0]

x=results_1_new['a']
y=results_1_new['b']
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.plot`, should be easier.

```
source_data.set_index("EUGROSHP")["EUGENHTH"].plot(kind='bar', legend=True)
plt.show()
```

Also, note that `results_1[results_1>0]` will give you a bunch of `NaN`s in your columns, did you mean to filter on a single column instead?

Comment: Although this doesn't actually solve the problem from the question, I'm upvoting because it encourages people to consider directly using pandas plotting functionality and hence avoid some common traps.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It does, but a little differently. I returned the favour :)